# gmail authentication Exception

Tags: java, email

When I am trying to receive an email through my java code, using IMAP, it always shows up an exception like this:

```
javax.mail.AuthenticationFailedException: [ALERT] Please log in via your web browser: https://support.google.com/mail/accounts/answer/78754 (Failure)
    at com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPStore.protocolConnect(IMAPStore.java:663)
    at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:345)
    at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:226)
    at other_utility.NewTest.main(NewTest.java:15)
```

Although I have used valid credentials, it still shows this exception. What is the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Gmail has an option called "Allow connections from less secure apps" which you can find under your account security settings. Try enabling that to see if it is the cause of your woes. If it is, at least it points you in the right direction.

The other thing I've run into with gmail is ipv6 (although this may be limited to SENDING emails). When using ipv6, gmail will refuse your connection if it can't complete a reverse DNS lookup on you. As an experiment, you might try

```
dig -4 mail.google.com
```

Then copy/paste the IP into your code and try running it. That's absolutely not a long term solution, but at least helps eliminate a possibility.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Acctually I already know about the "Allow connections from less secure apps" option, But I need to do all this things via my java code, And I am not able to do that. I have heard about gmail api's for email fetching in java, but i didn't know how do i get it and use it. It will be a great honor if you can help me out..